# Haskell check if function returned same value twice

Tags: list, haskell, divider

I'm working on a project and arrived at interesting issue. I have a function let's call it `foo` this function divides a given number by highest possible divider but not by iteself. If the highest divider is 1 then it returns the given number. For example number 21 first divides by 7 and returns 3 + it keeps returning 3 as there is no other divider other than 3 and 1.

```
ghci> foo 21
3
foo it
3
```

Now I want to save these steps taken into function that returns all steps in array. The current implementation is:

```
bar:: int-> [int]
bar x = x : bar (foo x)
```

The problem with this method is that it keeps returning the same value and never ends. Is there a way to check if the previous iteration of foo returned the same number and stop so it wouldn't result in infinite list?

Something like:

```
bar 21
[3]
```

```
instead of:
bar 21
[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3...]
```

In oop i would save last value into var and then compare it, however that's not case in haskell and I'm not sure how else it coulld be achieved

Comment: Another good general approach here is based on the classic Fibonacci example, `fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (drop 1 fibs)`. Given a list `xs` like `[1, 2, 3, 3, 3]`, the idiom `zip xs (drop 1 xs)` (or `zip xs (tail xs)`) pairs up each element with its neighbour, like `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3)]`. You can use functions like `span`/`break` or `takeWhile`/`dropWhile` to select the prefix you want. These operations can also be combined very naturally into a fold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if `x` is equal to `foo x`, if that is the case, we can stop the recursion, so:

```
bar :: Int -> [Int]
bar x
    | x == x' = [x]
    | otherwise = x : bar x'
    where x' = foo x
```

You here also return the given value first. If the first item in the list should be the number divided by the largest divider, you wan work with:

```
bar :: Int -> [Int]
bar = go . foo
  where go x
          | x == x' = [x]
          | otherwise = x : go x'
          where x' = foo x
```

Answer (score 1):

If a library style is preferred, one can also involve the [`unfoldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr) library function.

The general purpose code would be like this:

```
 λ> 
 λ> :type unfoldr
 unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
 λ> 
 λ> stepFn f v = if (v == f v) then Nothing else Just (let fv = f v in (fv, fv))
 λ> bar f v0 = v0 : L.unfoldr (stepFn f) v0
 λ>
```

As a guinea pig, we can pick a function that iteratively seeks an integer square root of, say, 709. Note it does not work for all numbers without a few extra tweaks, which would just obscure our purpose here.

```
 λ> 
 λ> foo n = div (n + div 709 n) 2
 λ> 
 λ> foo 1
 355
 λ> 
 λ> foo 355
 178
 λ> 
 λ> foo 26
 26
 λ>
```

So let's try with `bar`:

```
 λ> 
 λ> :type bar
 bar :: Eq b => (b -> b) -> b -> [b]
 λ> 
 λ> bar foo 1
 [1,355,178,90,48,31,26]
 λ>
```